Using Camel rest() in RouteTemplate
I would like to define a Route template that takes a REST endpoint as the source (from), so notionally something like this:
routeTemplate("restRouteTemplate")
    .templateParameter("toUri")     
    .rest("/api/v1/endpoint")     
        .description("Example Route Template")     
        .post("/testpost")     
    .routeId("exampleRoute")     
    .... further route definition....     
    .to("{{toUri}}");

Of course, this doesn't compile.
Context:
The deployment application is SpringBoot, Camel 4.4.1. However current testing is happening in a test Camel Main app to confirm this as a Camel question.
Rolling back from the restDSL allows the template to be defined, and used:
routeTemplate("restRouteTemplate")     
    .templateParameter("toUri")     
    .from("rest:get:/testget")     
    ......     
    .to("{{toUri}}");

However this doesn't allow restDSL/configuring RestDefinition programmatically and the following returns null for rd (unsurprisingly):
RestDefinition rd = routeTemplate("restRouteTemplate")     
    .templateParameter("toUri")     
    .from("rest:get:/testget")     
    ......     
    .to("{{toUri}}").getRestDefinition();

So my question is whether it's possible to define a rest endpoint as the entry to a RouteTemplate, and if so what am I missing?
Thanks in advance.
UPDATE:
So I discovered EndpointRouteBuilder, which can be substituted for RouteBuiilder as the parent class and allows:
routeTemplate("restRouteTemplate")
    .templateParameter("toUri")
    .from( restEndpoint( "post:/api/v1/endpoint")
        .description("Example Route Template")
        .consumes...
        .produces...
        .routeId("exampleRestRoute") )
    .process( exchange -> { ... })
    .to("{{toUri}}")

This is better, although may not be optimal as the verb is embedded. Any observations welcome.
